# Open Graph Api In Symfony2

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api

I have a website where users can listen to some tracks.  Now I want to integrate the possibility to share what each user is listening to(like in Deezer,NRJ,etc...).

After some research I found that I ought to use the Facebook open graph API.  In the tutorials I've found, they do use the Facebook php-SDK.

The [FOSFacebook Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle)is no longer maintained
So i wonder how can use the graph API in my Symfony application By Integrating the  Facebook php-SDK in my project(how is it possible) or any other way?

I Added "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*" in my composer.json file but it requires php 5.4.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to use. you want to use OG API or you want to create a OG-like API ?

Comment: I'm not upto date with the bundles you can use for this to use the SDK provided by Facebook, but you can just use something like Guzzle yourself if there isn't something you can get pre-built.